# Getting rid of old compiled assets in Rails 4 / Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

Our Heroku-hosted Rails 4 public asset directory (`~/public/assets`) is polluted with multiple versions of compiled assets, including ones we deleted long ago. I can't figure out how to get rid of them- it's driving me nuts. Tried:

1. `heroku run rake assets:clean`
2. `heroku run rake assets:clobber`
3. Running a bash session on Heroku and deleting them individually, or even deleting the entire `~/public/assets/` directory, but as soon as I re-login with another bash session they're still there!

Comment: Are you compiling assets locally or is Heroku precompiling them?

Comment: @SampritiPanda - Heroku is precompiling them

Comment: @Yarin: Did you solve the problem? I'm facing the exact same issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, guys. I now understand the problem and just in case it helps someone else:

You can not delete files via `heroku run bash` the way you would expect. This is by design. Have a look here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-heroku-works#dyno-manager

The important thing to notice:

> This [`heroku run bash`] will spin up a new dyno
>   ...
>   Changes to the filesystem on one dyno are not propagated to other dynos and are not persisted across deploys and dyno restarts.

Ok, that explains it. So, what if you can't get rid of old assets and `rake assets:clobber` doesn't solve it? Well, maybe something is hiding in cache.

**This solved it for me:**

1. Install the Heroku Repo plugin: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo
2. Purge the build cache: heroku repo:purge_cache
3. Rebuild the app: heroku repo:rebuild

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: This might sound like a no brainer, but did you try removing the files in git before pushing to Heroku?

Comment: I do not precompile locally which means there are no files in /public/assets. Therefore there is not /public/assets directory in git ;)

Comment: @Tom thanks for the update. Don't have time to test this myself right now but good to know there's a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since heroku is precompiling your asset files on production, there is nothing much you can do since heroku has a ephemeral file system.

According to Heroku

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted.

So every change that you make on heroku's file system gets wiped out.

Comment: But the problem is that the ephemeral filesystem is NOT clearing out the files when the dyno is stopped/restarted, as would be expected- instead it's retaining all the old asset files forever.